# Angular 2 - Event from service to component at same level

Tags: angular, events, authentication, angular-services, angular-components

I have an Authentication service that emits an event. When user logs in (via a LoginComponent), nav bar has to be updated (NavBarComponent) . These components are at the same level

First I tried to use EventEmitter, then I read we should not use it in a service. That is an anti-pattern.

So I tried https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service

**auth.service.ts**

```
import {Injectable}     from '@angular/core';
import { Subject }    from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

  private connectionState: boolean;
  private stateChangeSource = new Subject<boolean>();
  // Observable boolean stream
  stateChange$ = this.stateChangeSource.asObservable();

  constructor(private http: Http) {
  }

  changeConnectionState() {
    this.stateChangeSource.next(!this.connectionState);
  }
}
```

**login.component.ts**

```
import {Component, Inject} from '@angular/core';
import {AuthService} from './auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'login-component',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html'
})
export class LoginComponent {

  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {
    this.authService = authService;
  }

  login () {
    this.authService.changeConnectionState();
  }
}
```

**navbar.component.ts**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {AuthService} from './auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'navbar',
  templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
  providers: [AuthService]
})
export class NavbarComponent {

  authService: AuthService;
  connectionState: boolean;
  subscription: any;

  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {
    this.authService = authService;
    this.subscription = authService.stateChange$.subscribe(
      value => {
        this.connectionState = value;
      })
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

**navbar.component.html**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
...
    <a *ngIf="!connectionState" [routerLink]="['/login']">Connect</a>
    <a *ngIf="connectionState" (click)="disconnect()">Disconnect</a>
...      
</nav>
```

When I call

> this.authService.changeConnectionState();

from NavbarComponent, navbar is correctly updated.
But I would like to change the connection state from the loginComponent, then update the navbar. How can I do ?

[image]

**EDIT** :

Event is received in NavBarComponent :

```
this.subscription = authService.stateChange$.subscribe(
      value => {
        this.connectionState = value;
      })
```

But value is not updated in template. I have to change route in order to have the right value of 'connectionState'

Comment: If the components are at the same level and provided at one of them you should get an error message on the other, that there is no provider for the service.

Comment: Can you try to reproduce in a Plunker? Plunker provides a template for  Angular2 TS.

Comment: thx for your answer. I can't reproduce in a Plunker, I don't face the same problem. I removed "providers: [AuthService]" from NavBarComponent and there is an improvement :  "connectionState" value is changed but I have to change of route to see its modification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to delete

> providers: [AuthService]

from Navbar.component.ts

It was already set in my app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    LoginComponent
  ],
  providers: [
    AuthService
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

I had another bug due to my async call to login (not detailled in this post), and I don't know why. But this is not the subject.

Answer (score 1):

If the components are at the same level, then you can't share a service between them that is provided on one of them.

You need to provide a shared service on a common ancestors component, or a non-lazy-loaded `@NgModule()`